# Сырые сокеты в Windows 7

Tags: windows, сокеты, winsock, c++

Доброго времени суток.

Задали задачку по учебе - реализовать утилиту traceroute на udp пакетах под Windows. 
Да, я в курсе, что в самой винде есть tracert, но препод требует свое-родное.

Я создаю два сокета:

```
sock_send = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

для отправки UDP пакетов на узлы и

```
sock_recv = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
```

для получения ICMP ответа от узла.

Затем оба сокета я биндю и выставляю флаг `RCVALL_ON`.

Теперь, собственно, самое интересное.
Я отправляю на какой-нибудь IP свой UDP-пакет с TTL = 1, он исправно отправляется.
Затем я смотрю в WireShark и вижу, что мой домашний роутер прислал ICMP-ответ.
Однако моя программа этот ответ **не получает**.

Функция получения пакета:

```
res = recvfrom(sock_recv, recvbuf, BUFSIZE, NULL, (struct sockaddr*)&sar, &len);
```

Программа намертво виснет в функции recvfrom.

При этом если создать сокет с параметром `IPPROTO_IP`, то recvfrom прекрасно отрабатывает, **но** возвращает в recvbuf ICMP-сообщение от роутера, но без первых 8 байт ICMP-заголовка, только мой отосланный ранее IP-пакет. А ведь меня как раз этот заголовок и интересует, реакция роутера на TTL=1.

При гуглении я часто натыкаюсь на заявления о том, что поддержка сокетов в винде сильно урезана. Но вот где и каким образом это урезание произошло, на этот вопрос не нашел однозначного ответа.

Собственно, мои вопросы:

1. Можно ли в Windows 7 SP1 получить пакет через
       ICMP RAW сокет?
2. В чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: А программа запускается от имени администратора ? И покажите Ваш код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам код работающего кастомного tracerout'a (без файерволов, натов и т.д.). Проверял на виртуальной машине, т.к. сам сижу за тем, от чего остерегал Вас строчкой выше.

*P.S. Т.к. Вашего кода пока не увидел, предлагаю посмотреть на работающий.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

// PseudoHeader for calculation of UDP checksum
typedef struct _PseudoHeader
{
    unsigned int    SourceAddress;
    unsigned int    DestinationAddress;
    unsigned char   Zeros;
    unsigned char   Proto;
    unsigned short  Length;
} PseudoHeader;

typedef PseudoHeader FAR * LPPseudoHeader;

// Structure for IPV4 header
typedef struct _IPHeader
{
    unsigned char  ip_header_len : 4;  // 4-bit header length (in 32-bit words) normally=5 (Means 20 Bytes may be 24 also)
    unsigned char  ip_version : 4;  // 4-bit IPv4 version
    unsigned char  ip_tos;           // IP type of service
    unsigned short ip_total_length;  // Total length
    unsigned short ip_id;            // Unique identifier
    unsigned short ip_frag_offset;   // Fragment offset field
    unsigned char  ip_ttl;           // Time to live
    unsigned char  ip_protocol;      // Protocol(TCP,UDP,ICMP etc)
    unsigned short ip_checksum;      // IP checksum
    unsigned int   ip_srcaddr;       // Source address
    unsigned int   ip_destaddr;      // Destination address
} IPHeader;

// Structure for ICMP header
typedef struct icmp_hdr
{
    unsigned char  type;             // ICMP Error type
    unsigned char  code;             // Type sub code
    unsigned short checksum;
    unsigned short id;
    unsigned short seq;
} ICMP_HDR;

// Structure for UDP header
typedef struct udp_hdr
{
    unsigned short source_port;      // Source port no.
    unsigned short dest_port;        // Dest. port no.
    unsigned short udp_length;       // Udp packet length
    unsigned short udp_checksum;     // Udp checksum (optional)
} UDP_HDR;

// Structure for UDP payload packet
typedef struct udppacket
{
    UDP_HDR  udp;                    // UDP header
    char     messg[35];              // message
} UDP_PACKET;

// Structure for ICMP payload packet
typedef struct icmppacket
{
    ICMP_HDR icmp;                   // ICMP header
    DWORD   dwTime;                  // time
    char    cData[35];               // message
} ICMP_PACKET;

// Structure for storing information regarding a hop trace
typedef struct traceinfo
{
    int packetid;
    int ttl;
    int proto;
    int size;
    unsigned long saddr;
    unsigned long daddr;
} TRACE_INFO;


static int ICMP_SEQNO;
const  int UDP_DEST_PORTNO = 33434;   // 33434 to 33534
const  int FALLBACK_TO_ICMP = 1;       // Send ICMP echo requests if UDP fails
int    DESTINATION_UNREACHABLE = 0;
int    MAX_CONQ_ICMP_TIMEOUT = 2;       // Maximum consequtive ICMP hops that are allowed to tuneout
int    latency;

// Generic code to calculate the checksum of a packet
unsigned short CalculateChecksum( unsigned short *usBuf, int iSize )
{
    unsigned long usChksum = 0;
    //Calculate the checksum
    while (iSize>1)
    {
        usChksum += *usBuf++;
        iSize -= sizeof( unsigned short );
    }

    //If we have one char left
    if (iSize)
        usChksum += *(unsigned char*)usBuf;

    //Complete the calculations
    usChksum = (usChksum >> 16) + (usChksum & 0xffff);
    usChksum += (usChksum >> 16);

    //Return the value (inversed)
    return (unsigned short)(~usChksum);
}

// Calculate UDP checksum using pseudo header
unsigned short CalculatePseudoChecksum( char *buf, int BufLength, unsigned long  dest, unsigned long  src )
{
    //Calculate the checksum
    LPPseudoHeader lpPseudo;
    int PseudoHeaderLength = sizeof( PseudoHeader );

    lpPseudo = new PseudoHeader;
    lpPseudo->DestinationAddress = dest;
    lpPseudo->SourceAddress = src;
    lpPseudo->Zeros = 0;
    lpPseudo->Proto = 0x11;
    lpPseudo->Length = htons( BufLength );

    //Calculate checksum of all
    int iTotalLength;
    iTotalLength = PseudoHeaderLength + BufLength;

    char* tmpBuf;
    tmpBuf = new char[iTotalLength];

    //Copy pseudo
    memcpy( tmpBuf, lpPseudo, PseudoHeaderLength );

    //Copy header
    memcpy( tmpBuf + PseudoHeaderLength, buf, BufLength );

    //Calculate the checksum
    unsigned short usChecksum;
    usChecksum = CalculateChecksum( (unsigned short*)tmpBuf, iTotalLength );

    //Delete all
    delete tmpBuf;
    delete lpPseudo;

    //Return checksum
    return usChecksum;
}

// DNS lookup to get the IP address of the destination or host
int gethostaddr( char* pszHost, sockaddr_in& dest )
{
    // Initialize the destination host info block
    memset( &dest, 0, sizeof( dest ) );

    // Turn first passed parameter into an IP address to ping
    unsigned int addr = inet_addr( pszHost );
    //if its quad Address then OK
    if (addr != INADDR_NONE)
    {
        // It was a dotted quad number, so save result
        dest.sin_addr.s_addr = addr;
        dest.sin_family = AF_INET;

    }
    else
    {
        // Not in dotted quad form, so try and look it up
        hostent* hp = gethostbyname( pszHost );
        if (hp != 0)
        {
            // Found an address for that host, so save it
            memcpy( &(dest.sin_addr), hp->h_addr, hp->h_length );
            dest.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not a recognized hostname either!
            printf( "Failed to resolve %s\n", pszHost );
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// If the socket is readible then there is a response which can be read.
// If not readible then after timeout reurn no response status
int IsSocketReadible( SOCKET &s )
{
    struct timeval Timeout;
    fd_set readfds;

    readfds.fd_count = 1;
    readfds.fd_array[0] = s;
    Timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    Timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    return(select( 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &Timeout ));
}

//  Returns 1 on reaching destination, else returns 0
int ProcessIpPacket ( IPHeader *iphdr, unsigned long dest )
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;
    sockaddr_in source;
    iphdrlen = iphdr->ip_header_len * 4;
    static int no_hops;

    memset( &source, 0, sizeof( source ) );
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = iphdr->ip_srcaddr;
    // Destination unreachable is sent by the host that just previously sent an
    // ICMP time exceeded so don't print its information again
    if (!DESTINATION_UNREACHABLE || (source.sin_addr.s_addr == dest))
        printf( "\n %2d  %4d ms  %15s \n", ++no_hops, latency, inet_ntoa( source.sin_addr ) );

    /* Another way is to check for ICMP echo reply but this would only be sent
    for ICMP echo requests */
    if (source.sin_addr.s_addr == dest)   // Destination reached 
        return(1);

    return(0);
}

// Process the ICMP response. Extract the IP header and other information
int ProcessIcmpPacket( char* Buffer, int Size, unsigned long dest )
{
    unsigned short iphdrlen;
    int dest_reached = -1;
    IPHeader *iphdr = (IPHeader *)Buffer;
    iphdrlen = iphdr->ip_header_len * 4;
    ICMP_HDR *icmpheader = (ICMP_HDR*)(Buffer + iphdrlen);

    if ((unsigned int)(icmpheader->type) == 11)
        /*printf("  (TTL Expired)\n")*/;
    else if ((unsigned int)(icmpheader->type) == 0)
        /*printf("  (ICMP Echo Reply)\n")*/;
    else if ((unsigned int)(icmpheader->type) == 3)
        DESTINATION_UNREACHABLE = 1;

    dest_reached = ProcessIpPacket( iphdr, dest );

    return dest_reached;
}

// Find the response protocol
int ProcessPacket( char* Buffer, int size, unsigned long dest )
{
    IPHeader *ip = (IPHeader *)Buffer;
    int dest_reached = -1;

    switch (ip->ip_protocol) //Check the Protocol and do accordingly...
    {
    case 1:  //ICMP Protocol
        dest_reached = ProcessIcmpPacket( Buffer, size, dest );
        break;

    case 2:  //IGMP Protocol
        break;

    case 6:  //TCP Protocol
        break;

    case 17: //UDP Protocol
        break;

    default: //Some Other Protocol like ARP etc.
        break;
    }

    return dest_reached;

}

// Receive response from a readible socket and process it
int processResponse( SOCKET &s, unsigned long dest )
{
    char Buffer[1500];
    int  mangobyte;
    int  dest_reached = -1;

    if (Buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf( "malloc() failed.\n" );
        return dest_reached;
    }

    mangobyte = recvfrom( s, Buffer, sizeof( Buffer ), 0, 0, 0 );

    if (mangobyte > 0)
        dest_reached = ProcessPacket( Buffer, mangobyte, dest );
    else
    {
        printf( "recvfrom() failed.\n" );
    }
    return dest_reached;
}


/*void getSourceDestAddr(u16 *src_addr,u16 *dest_addr,sockaddr_in dest,sockaddr_in src)
{
int i=0;

src_addr[i]  =  src.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1;
dest_addr[i++] = dest.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1;

src_addr[i]  =  src.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2;
dest_addr[i++] = dest.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2;

src_addr[i]  =  src.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3;
dest_addr[i++] = dest.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3;

src_addr[i]  =  src.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4;
dest_addr[i] = dest.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4;

}*/

// Construct the IP header for the trace
void construct_ip_hdr( char *pack_data, TRACE_INFO trace )
{
    //Clear the data buffer
    memset( pack_data, 0, trace.size );
    int size = sizeof( pack_data );

    IPHeader *ip = (IPHeader *)(pack_data);

    ip->ip_version = 4;
    ip->ip_header_len = 5;     // in words (size is always 20 bytes for IPv4)
    ip->ip_tos = 0x0;
    ip->ip_total_length = htons( trace.size );
    ip->ip_frag_offset = 0x0;
    ip->ip_protocol = trace.proto;
    ip->ip_destaddr = trace.daddr;
    ip->ip_srcaddr = trace.saddr;
    ip->ip_checksum = 0;    // Don't worry, Kernel will do the needful
    ip->ip_id = htons( trace.packetid );
    ip->ip_ttl = trace.ttl;
}


/*
First construct the IP header.
Then construct the protocol packet
*/
int construct_proto_pack( char *packdata, TRACE_INFO trace )
{
    IPHeader *ip = (IPHeader *)(packdata);
    int packet_length = -1;
    static int portincr = 0;

    construct_ip_hdr( packdata, trace );

    if (trace.proto == IPPROTO_UDP)
    {
        //struct udp_hdr *udp           = (struct udp_hdr *)(ip + 1);
        if (portincr > 100)       // 33434 to 33534
            portincr = 0;

        UDP_PACKET *udp_pack = (UDP_PACKET *)(ip + 1);

        strcpy( udp_pack->messg, "Hello there!" );
        udp_pack->udp.dest_port = htons( UDP_DEST_PORTNO + portincr++ );
        udp_pack->udp.source_port = htons( 0 );
        udp_pack->udp.udp_checksum = 0;
        udp_pack->udp.udp_length = htons( sizeof( *udp_pack ) );

        // UDP Packet length = UDP header len + data len
        int udp_hdr_n_data_len = sizeof( *udp_pack );
        packet_length = ((int)(ip + 1) - (int)ip) + udp_hdr_n_data_len;

        ip->ip_total_length = packet_length;

        udp_pack->udp.udp_checksum = CalculatePseudoChecksum( (char *)udp_pack, udp_hdr_n_data_len, trace.daddr, trace.saddr );
    }
    else if (trace.proto == IPPROTO_ICMP)
    {
        //struct icmp_hdr *icmp         = (struct icmp_hdr *)(ip + 1);
        ICMP_PACKET     *icmp_pack = (ICMP_PACKET *)(ip + 1);

        icmp_pack->icmp.code = 0;
        icmp_pack->icmp.type = 8;
        icmp_pack->icmp.checksum = 0;
        icmp_pack->icmp.id = ICMP_SEQNO;
        icmp_pack->icmp.seq = ICMP_SEQNO++;
        icmp_pack->dwTime = GetTickCount();
        strcpy( icmp_pack->cData, "Hello there!" );

        // ICMP Packet length = ICMP header len + data len
        int icmp_hdr_n_data_len = sizeof( *icmp_pack );
        packet_length = ((int)(ip + 1) - (int)ip) + icmp_hdr_n_data_len;

        ip->ip_total_length = packet_length;

        icmp_pack->icmp.checksum = CalculateChecksum( (USHORT *)icmp_pack, icmp_hdr_n_data_len );
    }
    else
        return (-1);   // Protocol not supported

    return(packet_length);
}

// Populate the packinfo variable with parameters for a particular hop
void settraceinfo( TRACE_INFO &traceinfo, int packetid, int ttl, int proto, unsigned long dest, unsigned long src, int size )
{
    traceinfo.packetid = packetid;
    traceinfo.ttl = ttl;
    traceinfo.proto = proto;
    traceinfo.saddr = src;
    traceinfo.daddr = dest;
    traceinfo.size = size;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    sockaddr_in dest, src;
    TRACE_INFO traceinfo;
    char data[100];
    char hostname[70];

    ICMP_SEQNO = 1;

    // Start Winsock up
    WSAData wsaData;

    int char_size = sizeof( unsigned char );

    if (!(argc == 2))
    {
        printf( "Usage: %s %s \n", argv[0], "target_name" );
        return 1;
    }

    if (WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 1 ), &wsaData ) != 0)
    {
        printf( "Failed to find Winsock 2.1 or better" );
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a raw IP socket so that it can send/capture UDP and ICMP packets
    SOCKET sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP );


    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf( "\nCouldn't create socket" );
        return 1;
    }

    // provide our own IP header and not let the kernel provide one  

    int on = 1;
    if (setsockopt( sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (const char *)&on, sizeof( on ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf( "\nCouldn't set IP_HDRINCL" );
        return 1;
    }

    if (gethostaddr( argv[1], dest ) < 0)     // destination domain name or IP address
    {
        printf( "\n Couldn't resolve host %s \n", argv[1] );
        return 1;
    }

    //Retrive the local hostname
    if (gethostname( hostname, sizeof( hostname ) ) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf( "\nCannot retrieve hostname" );
        return 1;
    }


    if (gethostaddr( hostname, src ) < 0)               // Hostname  or IP address
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int packetid = GetCurrentProcessId();
    int written = 0;
    int proto = IPPROTO_UDP;    // UDP ping
    int pack_size = sizeof( data );
    int sockreadible = 0;
    int dest_reached = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int timed_out_cnt = 0;
    ULONG RequestTime = 0;
    ULONG ResponseTime = 0;

    printf( "\n Tracing route to %s [%s] \n", argv[1], inet_ntoa( dest.sin_addr ) );

    while (dest_reached == 0)
    {
        settraceinfo( traceinfo, packetid + count, count + 1, proto, dest.sin_addr.s_addr, src.sin_addr.s_addr, pack_size );
        if ((pack_size = construct_proto_pack( data, traceinfo )) > 0)
        {
            RequestTime = GetTickCount();
            written = sendto( sock, data, pack_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof( dest ) );

            if (written == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf( "\n Sending packet failed. Check permissions on this system" );
                printf( "\n Admin rights are required on XP" );
                return 1;
            }

            sockreadible = IsSocketReadible( sock );

            if (sockreadible)
            {
                timed_out_cnt = 0;
                ResponseTime = GetTickCount();
                latency = ResponseTime - RequestTime;
                dest_reached = processResponse( sock, dest.sin_addr.s_addr );

                // If destination is unreachable then switch to ICMP
                if ((DESTINATION_UNREACHABLE && (proto != IPPROTO_ICMP) && FALLBACK_TO_ICMP)) {
                    proto = IPPROTO_ICMP;
                    DESTINATION_UNREACHABLE = 0;
                }
                else if (DESTINATION_UNREACHABLE) {
                    printf( "\n Destination unreachable, so cannot proceed further" );
                    return 1;
                }

                count++;
            }
            else if (written > 0 && proto == IPPROTO_ICMP)
            {
                //request timed out even with ICMP packets then stop after MAX_CONQ_ICMP_TIMEOUT hops
                timed_out_cnt++;
                // If after consequtive MAX_CONQ_ICMP_TIMEOUT hops, request has timed out then stop
                if (timed_out_cnt >= MAX_CONQ_ICMP_TIMEOUT) {
                    printf( "\n Request has timed out even after %d hops, so not proceeding further\n", MAX_CONQ_ICMP_TIMEOUT );
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    printf( "\n Request timed out" );
                    count++;
                }

            }
            else if (written > 0 && FALLBACK_TO_ICMP)
            {
                // Try again with ICMP if UDP has failed for the ttl
                if (proto != IPPROTO_UDP)
                    count++;
                proto = IPPROTO_ICMP; // Don't go with UDP hereafter
            }
            else if (FALLBACK_TO_ICMP == 0)
                count++;

        }
    }

    closesocket( sock );
    WSACleanup();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Код из статьи на codeproject, чтобы нормально скомпилялось нужно задефайнить `_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS` и `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.