# Отправить данные в Ethernet как есть без заворачивания в протокол

Tags: сеть, сокет, ethernet

Как оправить данные в Ethernet как есть без заворачивания в протокол?
Исходя из найденных материалов, написал нижеприведённый код. Ошибок при отправке нет, но ничего не отправляется. Что не так?

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QString>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
//#include <netpacket/packet.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    SOCKET s;
    sockaddr_in RecvAddr;
    static const quint16 port = 8005;
    static const int sendBufSz = 2000;
    char sendBuf [sendBufSz];
    void init();
    void beforeExit();
    bool initSocketsLib();
private slots:
    void on_pushButtonClear_clicked();
    void on_pushButtonSend_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    if (initSocketsLib()){
        init();
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    beforeExit();
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::initSocketsLib(){
    WORD wVersionRequested;
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int err;

    /* Use the MAKEWORD(lowbyte, highbyte) macro declared in Windef.h */
        wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

        err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
        if (err != 0) {
            /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
            /* Winsock DLL.                                  */
            QMessageBox::critical(this, QStringLiteral("Ошибка инициализации библиотеки сокетов"), QString("WSAStartup failed with error: %1").arg(err));
            //printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
            return false;
        }

    /* Confirm that the WinSock DLL supports 2.2.*/
    /* Note that if the DLL supports versions greater    */
    /* than 2.2 in addition to 2.2, it will still return */
    /* 2.2 in wVersion since that is the version we      */
    /* requested.                                        */

        if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
            /* Tell the user that we could not find a usable */
            /* WinSock DLL.                                  */
            QMessageBox::critical(this, QStringLiteral("Ошибка инициализации библиотеки сокетов"), QString("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll"));
            //printf("Could not find a usable version of Winsock.dll\n");
            //WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        /*else
            printf("The Winsock 2.2 dll was found okay\n");*/
}

void MainWindow::init()
{
    s = INVALID_SOCKET;
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW); //Create a RAW socket
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
       QMessageBox::critical(this, QStringLiteral("Ошибка инициализации сокета"), QString("Код ошибки: %1").arg(WSAGetLastError()));
    int optval=1;
    setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL,  reinterpret_cast<char *>(&optval), sizeof(optval));  //Set it to include the header
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&optval, sizeof(optval));
    //setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&optval, sizeof(optval));

    RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RecvAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255");
}

void MainWindow:: beforeExit(){
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonClear_clicked()
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonSend_clicked()
{
    QString str = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText().simplified();
    if (str.isEmpty())
        return;
    if (str.size()%2 == 1)
        str = QStringLiteral("0")+str;
    bool ok;
    const int bytesToSend (str.size()/2);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i< str.size(); i+=2, ++j){
        sendBuf[j] = str.midRef(i, 2).toUShort(&ok, 16);
        if (!ok){
            QMessageBox::warning(this, QStringLiteral("Ошибка входных данных"), QString("Символ [%1] байт [%2] не является Hex-числом.").arg(i).arg(j));
            return;
        }
    }
    //Отправить
    const int retVal = sendto(s,sendBuf,bytesToSend, MSG_DONTROUTE, (SOCKADDR *) & RecvAddr, sizeof (RecvAddr));
    if (retVal == SOCKET_ERROR){
        QMessageBox::critical(this, QStringLiteral("Ошибка отправки данных"), QStringLiteral("Код ошибки: ") + QString::number(WSAGetLastError()));
        return;
    }
    if (retVal != bytesToSend){
        QMessageBox::critical(this, QStringLiteral("Отправлено ошибочное количество данных"), QString("Ожидалось %1 байт, отправлено %2 байт.").arg(bytesToSend).arg(retVal));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы хотите отправить широковещательный - то кажись вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730689/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81

Comment: Посмотрите вопросы с фразой "сырые сокеты "  "raw socket" http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/377132/%d0%a1%d1%8b%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-windows-7 (Windows)

Comment: Укажите Windows или Linux, это низкоуровневая вещь, она может для каждой ОС отличаться.

Comment: Raw socket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556525/raw-socket-implementation-in-windows